# I'll blow you away with my impressive display

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Some say that I simply manipulate the gullible,
>   Others think that people who use me are horrible.
>
> Really, who is to say, I come in many different forms,
>   Can I be only evil, or can someone control my storms?
>
> Even those who claim to abhor me, use me in a way,
>   Really, every time they smile, or that's what they say.
>
> Essential in most every fairy tale you've ever been told,
>   Real or not, strong or weak, my origin is very old.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> Magic?

Reasoning:

Some say that I simply manipulate the gullible

> You can use magic to trick people.

Others think that people who use me are horrible.

> Many people that people who use magic are evil

Really, who is to say, I come in many different forms,

> There are many different types of magic, ranging from transforming magic, to floating magic.

Can I be only evil, or can someone control my storms?

> Magic can also be used for good

Even those who claim to abhor me, use me in a way,

Really, every time they smile, or that's what they say.

> (From Joe-You-Know) "Your smile is magical" is a common phrase.

Essential in most every fairy tale you've ever been told,

> Many fairy tales have magic

Real or not, strong or weak, my origin is very old.

> Many people do not believe in magic, but people have believed in magic for a very long time.

Extra

> Also, the first letter of each line spells SORCERER, and a sorcerer uses magic.
>  The title is "I'll blow you away with my impressive display, because there are many types of magic, and magic can literally blow you away.

Comment: For the smile, there is a phrase, rot13(lbhe fzvyr vf zntvpny vf n pbzzba cuenfr gb hfr jura pbzcyvzragvat fbzrbar'f fzvyr). Also, this is right.

Comment: Is there something separate for "Even those who claim to abhor me, use me in a way,?"

Comment: No, it's intended to be tied with the next clue.

Answer (score 6):

This has already been answered, but another answer that kinda fits, you are:

> A lie

Some say that I simply manipulate the gullible,
Others think that people who use me are horrible.

> Lies are used to manipulate gullible people, and liars are considered horrible

Really, who is to say, I come in many different forms,
Can I be only evil, or can someone control my storms?

> Lies come in many forms, and a common discussion is whether "lying for a good cause" is justified

Even those who claim to abhor me, use me in a way,
Really, every time they smile, or that's what they say.

> Humour is often based on exaggerations, silly leaps of logic, and jokes are basically lies that entertain us

Essential in most every fairy tale you've ever been told,

> Fairy tales are things that didn't happen, so lying is essential for them to exist at all

Real or not, strong or weak, my origin is very old

> Lying is probably as old as humanity itself (maybe older - can chimps lie?)

Comment: Ooh, I really like this answer

Answer (score 2):

Just a random guess that is the answer a:

> Television Set.

Firstly the title

> Usually the television coming these days have world class displays and are equipped with cutting edge tech. Displays such as 4k, UHD , etc have stunning visuals.

Some say that I simply manipulate the gullible,
Others think that people who use me are horrible.

> Some people think that people get easily manipulated or persuaded by television as the content shown in it can be misleading sometimes and people may start believing like that. Some other people think that people who watch television are killing their time because it is sometimes regarded as idiot box.

Really, who is to say, I come in many different forms,
Can I be only evil, or can someone control my storms?

> Television comes in different forms flat, led, lcd, 3d etc and in a number of sizes too. For the next line we can say that its not that the television just shows bad content , it shows good content as well.

Even those who claim to abhor me, use me in a way,
Really, every time they smile, or that's what they say.

> The people who say that they hate TV , too sometimes watch it maybe to watch news or some documentary or just connect a Flash drive or a DVD player to watch some movies. They somehow use it. And that's when they smile.

Essential in most every fairy tale you've ever been told,
Real or not, strong or weak, my origin is very old.

> Here I can say that earlier the fairy tales we use to hear from our grandparents later came as an animated series or a movie which we have at any time watched in a TV. The [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television#History) of tv is quite old and unclear as they say it originated from ancient greek period.